# Catchable fatal error: Object of class Registry could not be converted to string

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I'm creating a shop in OpenCart and have just installed the OpenBay Pro module. I'm now getting the following error message on any page on the website:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Registry could not be converted to string in /var/sites/m/*shop name*/public_html/shop/system/library/log.php on line 6

log.php:

```
<?php
class Log {
    private $handle;

public function __construct($filename) {
    $this->handle = fopen(DIR_LOGS . $filename, 'a');
}

public function write($message) {
    fwrite($this->handle, date('Y-m-d G:i:s') . ' - ' . print_r($message, true) . "\n");
}

public function __destruct() {
    fclose($this->handle);
}
}
```

If anyone could shed some light for me (php is not my forte), it would be much appreciated, thanks!